# Xcode Crash IOS APP : dyld: Library not loaded, Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, frameworks, xcode9

I have Integrated a Framework in `Xcode` (custom framework). After launching application it is crashing with above error.

**What I have tried so far is:**

1. Added framework in Embedded Binaries Section in General tab.
2. "Always embed swift standard Libraries" Flag to true.

Error Message :

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F4839C88-8BF0-4E90-8B24-C71F3A008FCC/wificonfig.app/Frameworks/MedallionNet.framework/MedallionNet
>     Reason: image not found**

Comment: looks like your iOS and Xcode versions dont match

Comment: @iOSer Thanks for reply, i m using ios 11.4 and xcode 9.4